# How to iterate over a mongo document with an embedded doc using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have MongoDB data that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("602ad096f7449063397d41bd"),
    "name" : "1234/1236 Main St",
    "city" : "Indianapolis",
    "state" : "IN",
    "zip" : "46208",
    "total_units" : 2,
    "units" : [ 
        {
            "unit_num" : 1,
            "street" : "1234 Main",
            "bedrooms" : 3,
            "bath" : 1,
            "sqft" : 1225,
            "monthly_rent" : 800,
            "lease_expiration" : "2021-06-30"
        }, 
        {
            "unit_num" : 2,
            "street" : "1236 Main",
            "bedrooms" : 3,
            "bath" : 1,
            "sqft" : 1225,
            "monthly_rent" : 800,
            "lease_expiration" : "2021-07-31"
        }
    ]
}]}
```

Using python and PyMongo, I'm trying to iterate over all the entries, and not all the entries have multiple units, and return the monthly_rent and lease_expiration value. This is what I have in the shell:

```
db.property.find({active: true}, {_id: 0, name: 1, "street": 1,"units.monthly_rent": 1, "units.lease_expiration": 1}).sort({"units.lease_expiration": 1})
```

and it returns this:

```
{
    "name" : "1234/1236 Main St",
    "units" : [ 
        {
            "street" : "1234 Main St",
            "monthly_rent" : 800,
            "lease_expiration" : "2021-06-30"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "1236 Main St",
            "monthly_rent" : 800,
            "lease_expiration" : "2021-07-31"
        }
    ]
}
```

Within the python script, I want to iterate over each property and unit and print out name,"units.street","units.monthly_rent", "units.lease_expiration", but I can't seem to get it to traverse the units array. I'm testing this:

```
for prop in list(db.mycol.find({})):
        print(prop)
        print(prop["units.monthly_rent"])
```

The print(prop) prints out all the data as expected, but the other print statement gives an error: KeyError: 'units.monthly_rent'

Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

Adding aggregation query from *comments* below:

```
db.property.aggregate([
{ $project: { 
    "units": { 
        $filter: { input: "$units", as: "u", 
            cond: { $gte: [ "$$u.unit_num", 0 ] } 
        } } } 
}, 
{ $unwind: "$units" }, 
{ $project: { 
    "street": "$units.street", "
    monthly_rent": "$units.monthly_rent", 
    "lease_expiration": "$units.lease_expiration" } 
} 
])
```

Comment: Ideally, you should use an aggregation query to iterate over an MongoDB document's array field - and project the data as you want in your application.

Comment: Prasad_, when I try it using aggregation, it runs in the shell but gives me this error in python,  TypeError: aggregate() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: You need to post the aggregation query you had tried.

Comment: This works in the shell, but not in python. Also, it doesn't return the name field, only fields in the Units array: db.property.aggregate({ $project: { "units": { $filter: { input: "$units", as: "u", cond: { $gte: [ "$$u.unit_num", 0 ] } }, } } }, { $unwind: "$units" }, { $project: { "street": "$units.street", "monthly_rent": "$units.monthly_rent", "lease_expiration": "$units.lease_expiration" } } )

Comment: You need to post the aggregation query that is _not_ working (the PyMongo version:). Also, I included the aggregation from your comments into the post.

Comment: Oops! for prop in list(mycol.aggregate({
          "$project": {
            "units": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$units",
                "as": "u",
                "cond": {
                  "$gte": [ "$$u.unit_num", 0 ]
                }
              },
            }
          }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$units" },
        { "$project": {
          "street": "$units.street",
          "monthly_rent": "$units.monthly_rent",
          "lease_expiration": "$units.lease_expiration"
        }
        })):
        print(prop)

Comment: Try using `$addFields` instead of `$project` to return all fields.

Comment: I tried the aggregation in PyMongo - works fine. You just need to do proper _projection_.

Comment: @prasad, my query uses 2 $project, should I replace them both with $addFields or just one? And if just one, which one?

Comment: Use `$addFields` for the first projection. Then use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) with only the fields you need for the last one (read the linked document - it has all the information you need!)..

Comment: @prasad, thanks for your help.The query below works in the mongo shell but when I put it into pymongo I get this error:     return _op_msg_uncompressed(
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was <built-in function input>. Query: db.property.aggregate([ { "$addFields": { "units": { "$filter": { input: "$units", "as": "u", "cond": { "$gte": [ "$$u.unit_num", 0 ]} } } } },{ "$unwind": "$units" }, 
{ "$project":{ "street": "$units.street", "monthly_rent": "$units.monthly_rent","lease_expiration":"$units.lease_expiration"}}])

Answer (score 2):

You've to loop ver the units and print `unit.monthly_rent`

```
for prop in list(db.mycol.find({})):
        print(prop)
        for unit in list(prop['units']):
            print(unit['monthly_rent'])
```

You can't do `array['monthly_rent']` instead you've to do `array[0]['monthly_rent']` and so on

You've get each element and then you get access to the object inside the array

Comment: When I try that I receive this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'units'.

Comment: @VonHugenstein updated answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you! this approach is so much easier than what I was trying to do.